# Mysql Raw Count Only

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I use to PHP and Laravel Framework on my project.

Above code works perfectly

```
$users = User::select([
            'users.id',
            'users.name',
            'users.company',
            'users.country',
            'users.city',
            'users.email',
            'users.created_at',
            \DB::raw('SUM(reservations.dolar) as dolar'),
            \DB::raw('count(reservations.confirmation) as confirmation'),
        ])->join('reservations','reservations.user_id','=','users.id')
        ->groupBy('reservations.user_id');
```

Now Counting all reservation.confirmation column but I want to count only reservation.confirmation column values 1

How I can edit

```
\DB::raw('count(reservations.confirmation) as confirmation'),
```

this code

Comment: Have you tried with simply '...->where('condition')' or if it is in a join see https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#joins  in  Advanced Join Clauses section

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried see in https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#joins in the section "Advanced Join Clauses", you can add condition in Join function

```
$users = User::select([
        'users.id',
        'users.name',
        'users.company',
        'users.country',
        'users.city',
        'users.email',
        'users.created_at',
        \DB::raw('SUM(reservations.dolar) as dolar'),
        \DB::raw('count(reservations.confirmation) as confirmation'),
    ])->join('reservations', function ($join) {
                              $join->on('reservations.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
                                   ->where('reservations.confirmation', '=', 1);
    })->groupBy('reservations.user_id');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want have all sum `dolar` not depends with confirmation,
you can use 'case' statement:

```
\DB::raw('sum(case when reservations.confirmation=1 then 1 else 0 end) as confirmation')
```

or subquery:

```
\DB::raw('(Select count(*) FROM reservations WHERE user_id = users.id AND confirmation=1) as confirmation')
```